# Change The Menu Items after User Logged In

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to change the menu items whether the user logged in or logged out .
I search a lot on internet but didn't find a good solution.

This is my `SettingLauncher` class that returns the view and menu items.

A : Here I choose which items I have to show with `swiftkeychainwrapper`

```
import UIKit
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class SettingLauncher:NSObject,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDel       egateFlowLayout{

let cellId = "cellId"
let blackView = UIView()
let cellHeight : CGFloat = 50
var homeController: HomeController?
var defaultController : DefaultController?
//var productDetailController : ProductDetailController?

override init() {
    super.init()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(SettingCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

}

let settings : [Setting] = {
    let isLoggedIn : String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "myKey")

    // menu items
    let settingOne = Setting(name: .Profile, imageName: "profile-icon")
    let settingTwo = Setting(name: .Login, imageName: "login-icon")
    let settingThree = Setting(name: .Orders, imageName: "orders-icon")
    let settingFour = Setting(name: .Category,imageName: "category-icon")
    let settingFive = Setting(name: .Cancel, imageName: "cancel-icon")
    let settingSix = Setting(name: .SignOut, imageName: "login-icon")

    // A
    if isLoggedIn == "true" {
        return [settingOne,settingThree,settingFour,settingSix]
    }
    else{
        return [settingTwo,settingThree,settingFour]
    }

}()

let collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return cv
}()

//show menu
func showHambuger(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel)))

        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)

        let height : CGFloat = CGFloat(settings.count) * cellHeight
        let y = window.frame.height - height
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func handleCancel(setting: Setting){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.blackView.alpha = 0

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: window.frame.height,width: self.collectionView.frame.width,height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }

    }) { (completed: Bool) in
        if setting.name != .Cancel {
            //self.productDetailController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
            self.defaultController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settings.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingCell

    let setting = settings[indexPath.item]
    print(setting)
    cell.setting = setting
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]

    handleCancel(setting: setting)
}

}
```

And in my DefaultController class i Call the function like this

```
lazy var settingLauncher : SettingLauncher = {
    let launcher = SettingLauncher()
    launcher.defaultController = self
    return launcher
}()

@objc func handleHambugerButton(){
    settingLauncher.showHambuger()
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any issue with above code?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider replacing `var` with the `func` and don't forget to `reload` your view on users state changes. *I'm sure you would find better structures of `UICollectionView` implementation.*

```
private var collectionViewSettingItems = [String]()
var isLoggedIn: Bool {
    didSet {
        setupItems()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


func setupItems() {
    let isLoggedIn : String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "myKey")

  // menu items
  let settingOne = Setting(name: .Profile, imageName: "profile-icon")
  let settingTwo = Setting(name: .Login, imageName: "login-icon")
  let settingThree = Setting(name: .Orders, imageName: "orders-icon")
  let settingFour = Setting(name: .Category,imageName: "category-icon")
  let settingFive = Setting(name: .Cancel, imageName: "cancel-icon")
  let settingSix = Setting(name: .SignOut, imageName: "login-icon")

  if isLoggedIn {
      collectionViewSettingItems = [settingOne,settingThree,settingFour,settingSix]
  }
  else{
      collectionViewSettingItems = [settingTwo,settingThree,settingFour]
  }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionViewSettingItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingCell

    let setting = collectionViewSettingItems[indexPath.item]
    print(setting)
    cell.setting = setting
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]

    handleCancel(setting: setting)
}
```

Comment: i did it but when i initilize it in init() before super.init() like this (self.isLoggedIn = true )  the setupitems function would never be called

Comment: @kavehnaseri Can't you call function manually? I mean, call `setupItems()` where `isLoggedIn` value changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can store one flag in **UserDefaults** with **Unique KEY**.
For login user = true

when user logged out,  UserDefaults value should be change to false.

So when you user array you can retrieve this UserDefaults flag with KEY and if true then in  menu last option is logout(because user is login), and if  UserDefaults flag is false then menu last option is login.